# d3.geom.voronoi() does not return enaugh polygons

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

Here is [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aEtmq/88/)

I have an initial array of points(objects) that I draw on my chart and then I want to create a voronoi overlay for mouse events.

Form of my point objects: (Fiddle lines: 4-12)

```
point {
    id: 'id',
    x: xCoordinate,
    y: yCoordinate
}
```

And my voronoi code: (Fiddle lines: 95-112)

```
var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function(d) {return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.y); })
    .clipExtent([[0,0],[w,h]]);

//Create the Voronoi grid
graph.selectAll("path")
    .data(voronoi(points))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",function(d){return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";})
    .datum(function(d, i) { return d.point; })
    .attr("class", function(d,i) { return "voronoi " + d.id; })
    .style("stroke", "#000")
    .style("fill", "#2074A0")
    .style("opacity", ".3")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mouseover", function(d){document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = d.id})
    .on("mouseout", function(d){document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = ''});
```

Problem is that `var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()...` returns numberOfPoints-4 polygons. The first 4 polygons are missing regardless of number of points. If number of points is 4 or less, no polygons are returned.

Is this a bug or is there an error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem. The catch was in selecting all paths with `graph.selectAll("path")` instead of just paths appended after `data(voronoi(points))`

I added a class attribute to appended paths, and then select all paths of that class only.

[Here is the corrected fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aEtmq/103/)